# How do I get the text set on a ListView item

Tags: android, android-listview

**What I want to do**
I have several items in a ListView. When I longpress an item I have a contextmenu which pops up with several options. On of these options is "Share task". When the user selects "Share task" I want to have the Title/Text of the item they long-pressed to be retrieved and passed to a method.

**What's I've managed to do so far**
I have managed to get the id and position of the item in the listView which the contextmenu was called up using the method show below.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menuShare :
        //Identify list item on which editing needs to be performed
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        //METHOD TO SHARE TASK NEEDS TO GO HERE
        shareTask();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

**What I need help with**
I can't figure out how I can now get the text/title of the item on which the contextmenu was called. I intend to then pass this string to the shareTask() function to fire up a chooser. The title I have passed will then be used for example as the title of an email.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following code to get text of list item:

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
//list item's text on which long-pressed is performed
String text = yourListView.getAdapter().getItem(info.position).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks Waqas. I have come across an issue when I tried to implement this. When I created my Listview, I have given it an id attribute of "@+id/android:list". But when I try to replace the code you've give above in "yourListView" with "R.id.list" this item doesn't seem to exist. What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: Seems like your activity is of type **ListActivity**. So i believe you can simply use `this.getAdapter()` to refer to your ListView