# How do I refer to a list I have given an ID attribute of android:id/list in Java?

Tags: android, attributes, android-listview

In my XML, I have the following

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
```

How do I refer to this list view in my Java class files. R.id.*_* doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ID:

```
android.R.id.list
```

Comment: Thanks slukian. Think I'm getting somewhere with this. But why can't I now call android.R.id.list.getAdapter().
I'm trying to follow on from another question I asked on another thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762099/how-do-i-get-the-text-set-on-a-listview-item
Thanks again.

Comment: Figured it out in the end. To actually do anything with this list, you need to instantiate a ListView by doing

ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(**android.R.id.list**); //Thanks slukian for this

and then do whatever you like with it. Pretty sure its basic stuff, but might save a noob like myself a good few hours by sharing it here.

Comment: @Vim You can't call `android.R.id.list.getAdapter()` because `android.R.id.list` it's just an integer representing a system set ID. If you want the `ListView` element then you'll have to search the layout with `findViewById()` supplying the ID for that element(in your case the id of the `ListView` is `android.R.id.list` so you call `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`).